# Swift CollectionView set where to scroll

Tags: ios, swift, collections

So I have a collection view horizontal and I want when the user scroll to set the scroll where I want.

```
@IBOutlet var joke_cards: UICollectionView!

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        joke_cards.contentOffset.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x + 1000
        joke_cards.reloadData()

    }

}
```

But this doesn't work, it scrolls normally, I want to specify how much to scroll, any suggestions?

So I think I need to be a bit more clear, what I want is to flip through some cards horizontally thats why I need when the user stars to swipe to show the next cell in the middle

Comment: How it doesn't work? what is exactly happens?

Comment: Nothing.. it scrolls normally.. I want to specify how much to scroll

Comment: Are you sure `scrollViewWillEndDragging` is the right method for what are you want to achieve? what about `scrollviewdidenddecelerating`?

Comment: Thank you, it kinda works, with scrollToItem and scrollviewdidenddecelerating, but it doesn't work right, it should show the next joke in the middle, and preview left and right, and as you can see here: screencast.com/t/gv41nwxdVKs it skips some cards.. like the one with the "blonde girl", any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually scroll the user to a certain area you need first to define the area you need to scroll into view.  This will depend a little bit on where exactly you are trying to scroll, but if the goal is just to scroll 1000 points to the right you can define the rect and scrolling like so:

```
let destinationRect = CGRect(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x + 1000, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y, width: 1, height: 1)
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(destinationRect, animated: true)
```

Please note that scrolling will stop as soon as any part of the rect is visible, so if you want `contentOffset.x + 1000` to be in the center you will need to do some more math to create the `destinationRect`.

The other option, since you are using a `UICollectionView` is to figure out which cell is at the point you want to scroll to, and scroll that cell to a certain position.  In this example I safely unwrap the optional indexPath at the point you specified, and scroll that cell to be centered horizontally in the collectionView:

```
if let indexPath = self.joke_cards.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.frame.midY)) {
    self.joke_cards.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it kinda works, with scrollToItem and scrollviewdidenddecelerating, but it doesn't work right, it should show the next joke in the middle, and preview left and right, and as you can see here: https://www.screencast.com/t/gv41nwxdVKs it skips some cards.. like the one with the "blonde girl", any suggestions?

Comment: @Uffo I don't quite understand what exactly you're trying to do, but if there's a specific cell you're trying to scroll to the middle of the screen you just need to get the indexPath to that (however you choose) and call `scrollToItem` with that centered horizontally.  Do you know the cell you are trying to scroll the user to?

Comment: Well the user scrolls left or right and I want the next item to be centered in the middle, but if you look right now it doesn't scroll right, sometimes it scrolls too much, I also have paging enabled, you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap4cA.png what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: So you're trying to make it so that if the user scrolls right it just goes to the next item, no matter how much they try to scroll?

Comment: Yes, exactly thats what I want

Comment: This may be too much info for SO comments, but if you want to override the built-in functionality of UICollectionView scrolling you're probably going to have to disable user interaction on the collectionView and implement your own gesture recognizers.  It'll actually be pretty simple - add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, and using the delegate methods provided figure out which direction the user is swiping, figure out which indexPath you want to move the user to (either the next or previous, depending on direction), and use `scrollToItem...`